# Django context processors and middleware

Tags: django, middleware, processor, django-context

I'm trying to set a context variable in my custom context_processor which I craft using a request variable.  The request variable I'm trying to use is set in my custom middleware.  However I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'my_var'
```

It's weird though because my context variable shows up properly.  Is it because the Middleware  is processed after the Context Processor?  What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what method of middleware have you implemented.
process_request is called before any context processor is used, however process_response is called after all the templates processing.